# Change lower_case_table_name server parameter to 0 on Azure MySql

Tags: mysql, azure

I know that we can't change case sensitivity for table names for Azure MySql databases (v8). And it also shows in the documentation that only v5 is changeable. So, the question is, is there any way to change value for **lower_case_table_name** like going in shell and altering it. Something like that. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you please add additional information about any method/approach that you have tried?

Comment: There weren't any methods to do so. I asked if I can initialize mysql server with my .ini file from cli but they said there is no way to do that right now. So, currently the ball is in their court to implement this feature.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, it is not supported by Azure but after contacting their support, I got a little bit of clarification about the problem and you can upvote the feature [here](https://feedback.azure.com/d365community/idea/2b7f616f-ee24-ec11-b6e6-000d3a4f0da0), so that it might be implemented in near future.

Here is a thread about the problem in Microsoft Docs [Q&A](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/994555/case-sensitive-table-names-in-mysql.html)